# How to run linux executable file on Apache Jmeter

Tags: linux, shell, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I would like to seek for your assistance, example I have a shell script executable file and I want to call/run that with my Jmeter how can I simulate that one? Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

filename: aa.sh

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OS Process Sampler configured like:

[image]

and it will run your shell script and output the result.

[image]

Alternatively you can use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the following [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

```
"/bin/bash aa.sh".execute().text
```

Both approaches assume that your `aa.sh` file lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, if the location is different - provide [full or relative path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html) to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSR223 Sampler.
Add this line : /bin/bash aa.sh".execute().text